# How can I fix dbeaver light theme text display?

Tags: dbeaver, manjaro, i3

I'm using dbeaver 6.0.4 on Manjaro+i3wm 4.14. some text color is similar to background. When I switch dark theme everything is ok. I have tried all the light theme and I don't want to dark theme. what can I do to fix this?

[ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maHuC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already resovled by install from eclipse marketplace not from os